# how to implements junit testing in fragments and how to implement button click in junit testing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, junit3

Button click perform and calling a method in `junit3` is not working.
Implementing in `junit3` in android fragment is not working?

Answer (score -1):

The way we do unit testing at my current workplace is by using Robolectric.

This is more UI testing than unit testing. Also we use expresso. In past I also used Calabash.

```
//we use Junit4 like in the tutorial.
private static final String DEFAULT_TEXT = "Whatever";
@Before
public void testSetup(){
     YourActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).get();
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
   activity = null; 
}

@Test
public void testOnClick() {
    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);

    editText.setText(DEFAULT_TEXT);
    button.performClick();

    assertThat(textView).containsText(DEFAULT_TEXT);
}
```

[Example](http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/)

Comment: The question is asking for fragments, not activities